# Wordpress .htaccess problems

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I created a plugin for Wordpress, and currently the url for the plugin is:
localhost/player/?id=123

I want to create a url rewrite so the url looks like: localhost/player/123

I tried using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^player/(.*) player/?id=$1
```

But that's not working. Whenever I go to localhost/player/123 I just receive the wp page not found page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^player/(.*)$ player/?id=$1
```

Comment: That is a perfectly valid rewrite rule which should work. The error is obviously somewhere else. What does /player/?id=123 bring up? A 404 or valid resource?